# static routing to an interface, that is only reachable from inside the network

Tags: routing

ISP <-> ROUTER_A <-> ROUTER_B

```
ROUTER_A LAN: 192.168.5.1
ROUTER_B WAN: 192.168.5.215
ROUTER_B LAN: 192.168.16.1
```

I need to get from ROUTER_A to ROUTER_B LAN.

What routing I need to update in which router to get there?

Subnets are all /24.

Comment: ROUTER_A>ip route 192.168.16.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.5.215 Please supply full subnet masks for each of network as router B WAN and ROUTER A LAN for class C overlaps.

Comment: You router IP address looks as if they are in same network. What are the subnet mask of each?

Comment: You don't give enough information. Edit your question to include the device models and configurations.

Comment: Why was datagram's answer moved to the comments? He/she did answer the question correctly imho. For A to be able to reach the land behind B it needs a route to 192.168.16.0/24 (assuming it is /24) via 192.168.5.215

Comment: updated with subnet.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to get to 192.168.16.0/24 from router A itself then as @Datagram.Network wrote the only route needed is on A, for 192.168.16.0 with B's WAN interface as gateway, so on A (in Cisco router syntax):

```
ip route 192.168.16.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.5.215
```

However if you actually meant that LAN_B needs to have connectivity to the WAN/Internet, then (in addition to the above) B would need a default route with A as next hop, so on B:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.1
```

Note that if the WAN is the public Internet then A would also need to do NAT.

Edit: I was assuming A already had a default route to the ISP, which I should not have assumed, so @Gadeliow's answer is correct in that A also needs

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <ISP-address>
```

But again, the default routes on A and B are *not* needed when the requirement is to only have connectivity between A and the-LAN-behind-B.

Answer (score 0):

it is all about ***ROUTE*** and ***REVERSE ROUTE***

[image]

@ ***router A***

1. you should be able to ping ISP and ROUTER B
2. you need default route to access ISP resources in form of
   ***`ip route 0.0.0.0  0.0.0.0 X.X.X.X<isp ip>`***
3. you must has route to reach network behind router B
   ***`ip route 192.168.16.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.5.215`***

@ ***router B***

1. you should be able to ping  ROUTER A
2. you need  default route to access what is behind Router A in form of
   ***`ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.1`***